# have two objects in ng-repeat mixed/merged

Tags: arrays, angularjs, merge, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've two objects, for example:

```
[
  {
    "some": "thing",
    "lol": "asd",
    "rotfl": "id321ddk",
    "hello": "world000"
  },
  {
    "some": "thing2",
    "lol": "asd2",
    "rotfl": "oddddk2",
    "hello": "wwwworld2"
  },
  {
    "some": "thing3",
    "lol": "asd3",
    "rotfl": "idkkk3",
    "hello": "worldd"
  }
]
```

^ the first: and now the second:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "img": "link",
    "name": "idk"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "img": "link2",
    "name": "asdette"
  }
]
```

As you can see, they are very different, everything also the length.
I need to do something like this:

```
[
  {
    "some": "thing",
    "lol": "asd",
    "rotfl": "id321ddk",
    "hello": "world000",
    "id": 1,
    "img": "link",
    "name": "idk"
  },
  {
    "some": "thing2",
    "lol": "asd2",
    "rotfl": "oddddk2",
    "hello": "wwwworld2",
    "id": 2,
    "img": "link2",
    "name": "asdette"
  },
  {
    "some": "thing3",
    "lol": "asd3",
    "rotfl": "idkkk3",
    "hello": "worldd"
  }
]
```

So I'd like to add to the first array the second. But if the second array is "finished", so stop adding it.

**We can also don't have the "id" field, it's not important..**

Is that way possible in some way in angularJS?
i'm using angular and ionic.
Thanks!

Comment: You want merge by what? By same index? Sounds bad.

Comment: The nth element of the first with the nth element of the second. If the second hasn't any more element, It stop adding because there is nothing to add to the first :) (or if it's easier it could repeat, so if the first is longer then the second, you could re-add the second to the first re-starting from the first element of the second with the nth element of the first).
Hope it's ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
var arr1 = [
  {
    "some": "thing",
    "lol": "asd",
    "rotfl": "id321ddk",
    "hello": "world000"
  },
  {
    "some": "thing2",
    "lol": "asd2",
    "rotfl": "oddddk2",
    "hello": "wwwworld2"
  },
  {
    "some": "thing3",
    "lol": "asd3",
    "rotfl": "idkkk3",
    "hello": "worldd"
  }
];
    var arr2 = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "img": "link",
    "name": "idk"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "img": "link2",
    "name": "asdette"
  }
];

//Assuming arr2.length <= arr1.length
for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  angular.extend(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
}

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: `Assuming arr2.length >= arr1.length` -> it's the contrary, `arr1.length >= arr..length`

Comment: @LudovicoLoreti yeah, updated the comment, the code stays the same though.